# CSS does not override inherited values

Tags: css, inheritance, html, overriding, border

I have an Html that contains something like:
(Multiple divs within div A).

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

My css looks like that:

```
.a div {
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}

.b {
    border: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

For some reason b's values will not override a. 
however, if i just write a rather than "a .div" i won't get the behavior expected for the other divs inside a.

The only way i got this to work is using "important!" (ie "border: none!important";) but that seems less than elegant.

would love any ideas as to what is going on there..

Ehud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.a div` has a higher specificity than `.b`.
If you want the css for .b to override the .a one, give it a higher specificity still, for instance `.a div.b`.

(Or you can use `!important`, yes, but that is not recommended here.)

Comment: That is somewhat unintuitive, at least for me, but works like a charm (BTW i just used ".b div" and that worked too).

Comment: That's odd, `.b div` isn't supposed to work, since you have no divs inside your .b, at least not in your example. Anyway, specificity is a very important concept within CSS, I'd suggest you read up on it.

Answer (score 3):

Your selectors are wrong.

Instead of

```
a. div {
```

Write

```
div.a {
```

(select any div with a class of "a")

Instead of

```
b {
```

(which will actually try to style all **b** elements)

Use

```
.b {
```

(which says select anything that is defined by the class of "b" )

**EDIT** (in response to response)

To select all divs that are inside a div with the class of "a", use the following selector:-

```
div.a div
```

Comment: My selectors (in the code) were fine, but what I put in the question was obviously mistaken. My selectors are ".b" and ".a div". Sorry, I'll edit the original post. The solution, however, does not work for me.

What im trying to select are not all the divs with a class a, but all the divs under an element whose class is a.

Comment: Edited with a new selector for you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

**Specificity score** is calculated by the CSS compilers, the highest score of among declaration gets to modify the content.

Score is generally calculated by this order:

```
inline   id-element   class-element   no.-of-elements
  $          $             $                $
```

**($) -> 1 if the respective type of specificity exists in code

($)    -> 0 if the respective type of specificity doesn't exists in code**

So here 
for `.a div` score will be 0012
for `.b` score will be 0011
Clearly first one wins so it gets to modify the content even though `.b` tries to override `.a div`
**(OR)**
you can use `!important` in the declaration to finalize that declaration